# Obtaining certified copy of old UK adoption ruling

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, advice

I am trying to obtain a certified copy of an adoption/custody ruling that was made in a UK county court in 1971. The ruling concerns my sibling and it is on their behalf that I am trying to obtain it as they are no longer resident in the UK. I know which court it was and I have the dates of the case.

I really have no idea how to go about this or whether it's even possible. Should I contact the court concerned directly, the National Archives or something else?

Any pointers or advice gratefully received.

Comment: Have you tried the National Archives at all? The 2 pages I just looked at said that NA has or can access the catalogue of many other archives and give contact information for the other archives. A good starting point maybe?

Comment: The UK [General Register Office](https://www.gov.uk/general-register-office) can supply certificates - it holds records of births, deaths, marriages, civil partnerships, stillbirths and adoptions in England and Wales.